# IOS Swift Parse - Querying specific column(Array) in a row

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Does anyone know how to query a specific column in a row.(parse data)

Ex: I have a class "user" where I have a column which is an array, i want to get array size/ length of that particular column.

Let's say Array column contains : {A,b,c}

I want to get it's count which is 3. (using IOS Swift)

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's as simple as casting that property as an array and then getting the count:

```
var arrayColumn:[String] = pfObject["arrayColumnKey"]
let count = arrayColumn.count
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan for your reply. Actually I'm new to this IOS swift, could you please specify me little more based on my code below:

var query1 = PFQuery(className:"TestClass")
query1.whereKey("username",  equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())

query1.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (users,error) -> Void in
                        for user in users {
// here i want to return array count for the column name (TestArray) of row (current user).
//How can i implement your code here?
 var arrayColumn:[String] = user["arrayColumnKey"]
                            let count = arrayColumn.count
 }

Comment: Also i'm getting the below error

 var arrayColumn:[String] = objects["arrayColumnKey"] 
error:// 'String' is not identical to 'AnyObject'

Comment: you will always get an error using the above method because your declaring the variable as an array of string and then assigning an array of PFObjects try using if let arrayColumn : [String] = PFObject["arrayColumnKey"] as? String { let count = arrayColum.Count}